# Android Sender app with default receiver : receiving unexpected pause state during autoplay

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am writing a sender app for Android, using the CastCompanionLibrary. The integration is very simple so far, but a couple quick things I have noticed:

Playing with autoPlay set to true results in a few paused states being returned before it actually plays

```
Calling load with stream url xxxxxx with autoplay true
got new player state PAUSED idleReason NONE
got new player state PAUSED idleReason NONE
got new player state PLAYING idleReason NONE
```

This is just some simple logging, but as you can see, it returns 2 paused states, then (a second or 2 later), it returns the play state. This is far from ideal, as I basically have to suppress those 2 paused states, or the UI will flip to the idle state, then seconds later, back to the correct state.

Is this a known bug? or expected for some reason. Perhaps it is just indicating an idle state before autoplay begins, but why twice, and why bubble it up at all if autoplay is true?

Edit : Filed an issue here : https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=443

Comment: On the sender side, I see BUFFERING followed by PLAYING, so I don't see the PAUSED at all. What type of media are you playing?

Comment: MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(streamUrl)
                    .setContentType("audio/mpeg")
                    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                    .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                    .build();

Comment: As for the stream url, it is going to hit our api and be redirected to a 128k mp3 on a secure edge-cast server, e.g. https://ec-media.xxx.com/asdf.128.mp3

Comment: What receiver are you using?

Comment: VideoCastManager. It doesn't seem to matter though. I even built my own very simple CastManager that used a RemoteMediaPlayer, and I had the same problem

Comment: I was asking about the receiver, I guess you confused that with something else.

Comment: oh sorry. yes. the default media receiver.

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing PAUSED (I imagine you see a number and you are mapping that to PAUSE or BUFFERING, etc)? The states that I see are 4, 4 and then 2 that maps to BUFFERING, BUFFERING and PLAYING

Comment: Yes, Im sure. My untouched logs are I/asdf    (19029): loaded media
I/asdf    (19029): New player state and reason 3 0
I/asdf    (19029): New player state and reason 3 0
I/asdf    (19029): New player state and reason 2 0

Comment: however, since you have way more experience with the cast sdk than I do, and are convinced this is abnormal behavior, I will go back to the drawing board tomorrow with some further testing and hopefully have more info. thanks for helping out!

Comment: Sure. Please let us know if you still see that there is an issue; creating a simple test case is ideal so we can recreate since, as I mentioned earlier, when I tried CastVideos-android, I wasn't able to reproduce that.

Comment: Hi Ali, So I tested with CastVideos-Android, and got the same problem I reported above. The only change I made was changing 3 lines in Utils.java here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/utils/Utils.java#L474 to this : https://gist.github.com/jonschmidt/e5bee805ee88a13e5ae9

Comment: oh and I also changed the receiver id to the default receiver

Comment: Ok, so lets try to find out what is happening. Would you please open a ticket at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list and provide this info and a reference to our conversation so we can move this communication there and get to the bottom of it? Thanks.

Comment: Done : https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=443 , please let me know if this is sufficient. Thanks!